# Ubuntu installer not picking up Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04. In the installer the "Install alongside" option is not there so I clicked "something else". I have been all over Google and Youtube. When other people click "something else" there is a bar at the top showing free space and I'm assuming it is the Windows partition but it isn't on mine. Its just one long grey bar saying I have 500 GBs free. Please help me as I don't know what to do. I have also allocated free space for Ubuntu so I'm assuming it should show free space and the space that Windows is on, right?

Comment: Have you tried making the partition that Linux will be using in Windows before trying to install? If you want to know how to make partitions in Windows check out this video and start at 6:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeSaVzyPY8k

Comment: Sorry for responding after so long but i eventually found a fix which is the one **Rod Smith** suggested

Comment: @Drenii If you found a solution to you problem please post it as an answer to this question so that other users can benefit from the solution. You might be interested in reading about [how to reference others content](http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing) and [how to write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer).